# What's the difference between normal goo and red goo in World of Goo?

Tags: world-of-goo

I've started Chapter 3 of World of Goo, and I'm a bit stumped. What is the purpose of the red goo balls?

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with them...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The red goo balls become matches when they are used.  When put near fire, they will burn and then transfer this fire down the chain.  This can either be part of the goal (burn so that something moves) for the level or one of the hazards for the level.

Comment: Ah, I see. That explains the big fire. :)

Answer (score 2):

Red goo is flammable ([source](http://worldofgoo.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Goo)).